# JavaScript functions cannot be call one from another

Tags: javascript

I get desired output from below code. These are two JavaScript function expressions for printing data

```
(function(){
var getData=function()
{
   console.log("getdata");
},
setData=function()
{
  getData();
  console.log("setData");
};
setData();
})();
```

But when I try something like this in another page.I didn't get desired output.

This is my code.

```
var employeesList = {
    getemployees: function () {
    var data= getData("Employees/GetEmployees");
    },
    init: function () {
        this.getemployees();
    }
}.init();

  var getData = function (url) {
    var error = false;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            return data;
        },
        error: function () {
            return error = true;
        }

    });
};
```

I got an error like this.
getData is not a function
please help.

Comment: move `var getData = function (url) {` above `var employeesList = {`

Comment: Make sure function is defined or accessible in that [scope](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-scope-in-javascript).

Comment: Or declare it like `function functionName() {}` instead of using a variable. That way it'll be usable before being declared.

Comment: Now it is working.i forget the concept JavaScript Hoisting. Thanks for remembering me.

Comment: function functionName() {} this is function declaration. This will initialize on initial function call.

Comment: @ Arun P Johny. You can post this comment as answer. So that i can up vote you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can't use a variable before have defined it, so you have to declare `getData` before `employeesList`
- The variable `data` in `getemployees` couldn't be accessible, I added a return there, so you can use its value in `init`

```js
var getData = function (url) {
    var error = false;

    /*$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            return data;
        },
        error: function () {
            return error = true;
        }

    });*/
    return 'test_result';
};

var employeesList = {
    getemployees: function () {
        //Here you should return the result
        return getData("Employees/GetEmployees");
    },
    init: function () {
        var res = this.getemployees();
        console.log(res);
    }
}.init();
```

I hope it was clear, bye.

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods to define "function":

1. var func_name = function(){...}
2. function func_name() {...}

The difference is that when you use the second one, it can be called before being declared.

```
var employeesList = {
    getemployees: function () {
    var data= getData("Employees/GetEmployees");
    },
    init: function () {
        this.getemployees();
    }
}.init();

  //var getData = function (url) {
function getData (url) { // <====== change to this
    var error = false;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            return data;
        },
        error: function () {
            return error = true;
        }

    });
};
```